# Pasar html de index.html (principal) y que al apretar un botón me redirija y pinte el html a otra página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pasar html de **index**.html (principal) y que al apretar un botón me redirija y pinte el html a otra página.

Quiero que lo que tengo dentro de un div en mi página principal me lo pinte en la otra página dentro de otro div al apretar un boton y me redirija a esa página.

El html lo quiero pasar por que es un generador de formularios..

al hacer un generador de formularios apretando botones voy insertando html (labels,inputs, textarea...) dentro de un div en el index.hmtl(página principal). Lo que quier es que cuando termine ya de insertar html ahí por finalizar el formulario que al aptretar a un botón que ese html del formulario me lo pinte en otra página(otra.html) y por ejemplo dentro de otro div de la página otra.html y posupuesto que me redirija a otra.html

Meter este html del div id=texto de la pagina principal index.html:

```
   <div id=texto>
       <form id="#" name="formulario" action="#" method="#">
                <div  class="panel-body">

                    <section class="container-fluid" style="word-break: break-all;  word-wrap: break-word;" class="resultado" id="resultado">
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div id='oculto' class="text-center oculto">
                    <button type="submit" id="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm boton elemento1">Guardar</button>
                </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

                  </diV>
```

a otra página que he creado **otra.html** por otro div id="html_copiado":

```
      <div id="html_copiado">

      </div>
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta es muy amplia. El código que pones no tiene relación con tu problema. Básicamente lo que quieres hacer es guardar _el estado_ de tu sesión. Es relativamente trivial hacerlo con frameworks como AngularJS, Angular, Vue, React, etc., pero yo habrás observado, complicado sin el apoyo de JavaScript. Investiga alguna de esas opciones y realiza todas las preguntas que necesites, siempre debes incluir un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es insertar datos de un formulario, en una página tal vez, lo que necesitas es utilizar ventanas modales. Podrías crear tu contenido en un modal y después insertar el mismo, en la página en la que estas trabajando, en un div. [Modal en Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Esto evitaría que mandes datos de página a página y que utilices session storage o javascript más complejo.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos formas:

1. Usar [sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), que elimina los datos generados al cerrar el navegador. Si quieres que estos datos persistan entonces usa [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Si ambos html están en el mismo dominio accedes a los datos como si de un JSON se tratase. Mírate la documentación y si tienes dudas pregunta en los comentarios ;-).
2. Usar parámetros GET. Al redirigir a ese otro html puedes mandar los datos que necesitas en la URL y usar JavaScript para insertarlos en el nuevo div. [Aquí te dejo un snippet](https://gist.github.com/erknrio/e6fe825b5c5df8bd488d) que convierte la URL en un array. Hace tiempo que no lo uso pero te servirá de guía. Pero cuidado porque las URL tienen un límite de 2000 caracteres si no recuerdo mal.

**¿Cómo usar sessionstorage?**

Al final de este documento tienes un ejemplo hecho con sessionStorage pero el uso de localStorage es el mismo.

Asumo que sabes como obtener los datos de tu index.html por lo que me centro sólo en la parte de comunicación entre páginas.

Usando pares clave => valor guardamos todos los datos de esta forma: `sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`. Eso se almacena en el dispositivo del usuario, si usas Chrome pulsa F12 y vete a una pestaña llamada "Application" y allí busca "Session Storage". Así podrás ver tus datos en todo momento ;).

Una vez tengas todos los datos guardados, en otra.html simplemente los lees (ya fueron guardados con anterioridad por lo que están disponibles).

Con `var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');`. Son ejemplos sacados de la documentación citada más arriba.

No hace falta que inicialices nada ni hagas cosas extrañas, sessionStorage lo tendrás disponible tal cual.

Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/erknrio/w4x4gqr7/

Comment: no lo acabo de entender sabrias hacerme un ejemplo de codigo con lo de ssesionstorage? como pasas el html de una pagina a otra?

Comment: Te expliqué un poco la teoría, en cuanto tenga tiempo intentaré hacer un ejemplo más práctico.

Comment: perfecto!!! será de gran ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Si sessionstorage te da problemas prueba con localstorage y cuando termines haces un localStorage.clear() para eliminar todo.

Comment: Justamente iba a dar una respuesta como ésta. Lo que tienes que es guardar en el sesionStorage los datos que quieres mostrar en tu otra página. Ejemplo práctico: pagina1.html tengo un input y le pongo de texto "hola", le doy a "enviar" al momento de darle a enviar guardo en sesionStorage ese hola que escribí, al clicar el enviar se abre pagina2.html desde el JS DE ESTA PÁGINA lees el sessionStorage y creas un elemento o lo que necesites (document.createElement("input")) y le pones tu valor.

Comment: En tu caso, como lo quieres no son valores de los campos, si no los elementos en sí. Entonces tendrías que saber qué elementos seleccionó el usuario. Pienso en algo así `{"section":{"inputs":[{"sort":1,"label":"Usuario"},{"sort":2,"label":"Password"}]}}` se puede llegar a complicar muchísimo, dependiendo de las necesidades y las opciones que tenga el usuario. Luego en la otra página leer ese objeto y según los datos añadir un elemento u otro, según el orden (lo de sort lo he puesto yo para saber sí poner poner un elemento u otro antes que otro)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una rutina **PreView** en la cual abres una ventana y despliegas el contenido de la div que quieres.

Ejemplo:

```
// Rutina para Pre Visualizar el Formulario
preview = function(id) {

 // Abrir la Ventana donde Visualizar el Elemento:
 var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=800,height=600");

 // Obtengo el Elemento que quiero Visualizar:
 var el = document.getElementById(id);

 // Despliego en la Ventana el Elemento a Visualizar:
 myWindow.document.body.innerHTML=el.innerHTML;
}
```

En el siguiente link te dejo un ejemplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/8kyag6gk/